# Webpack production, prevent overwrite existing files

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-2, msdeploy

Is it possible to execute webpack that previously generated files with chunknames like

**1.a7285335770fffaf3175.js**, 
**2.vsgg5335770fffaf587.js**

does not get overwritten on compile?

I ask this because on every compile, the files (when the code stays the same) get overwritten with the same name, so only the "modified-date" change.

Because of this my sync-program of choice (msdeploy.exe) is looking for that date-change and sync ALL the files again, although the modified-date has changed

Comment: Why don't you try using git for deployment (if you can, of course)?

Comment: Why not tell msdeploy to look at checksums instead of timestamps? [WebDeploy/MSDeploy Quick Tip: Only Deploy Changed Files](https://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/06/03/webdeploymsdeploy-quick-tip-only-deploy-changed-files/)

Comment: @zero298 Thank you! This was exactly what i needed, didn't know about this one (...-useChecksum=true"...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than change how webpack operates, you can have WebDeploy/MSDeploy use different mechanism to check for changes.  Drawing from this article: [WebDeploy/MSDeploy Quick Tip: Only Deploy Changed Files](https://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/06/03/webdeploymsdeploy-quick-tip-only-deploy-changed-files/), there are 2 main ways to check for differences:

1. Timestamp (the default)

MSDeploy will simply compare the timestamp of resources in order to determine whether or not a new build needs to occur.

2. Checksum (what will probably work for you)

Using the `-useChecksum` switch when you execute MSDeploy will have MSDeploy use file checksums, which means that both files actual content will be compared, rather than file metadata, will be compared to check for changes.

Additionally, according to the article:

> If you are deploying during the MSBuild process you can add the
>   `/p:MSDeployUseChecksum=true` argument which will set the MSDeploy flag.